# Newbie question about Android Studio and button not syncing in main activity

Tags: android

Here is the tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=289&v=OGfZpfn-dGI

In my android studio it doesn't recognize the button iv'e name them

`android:id="@+id/top_button"`
`android:text="top button"`
`android:text="button 2"`
`android: android:id="@+id/button_2"`

`top_button.setOnClicklistner {
            println(top button was clicked)`
`Button_2.setOnClicklistner {
            println(Button)`

Comment: Please don't just link to a video. You need to explain exactly what the issue is, and include any relevant code and XML. As it is now, I can't even tell if you're asking about a button in Android Studio itself, or one in an app you're writing. If it is about your app, then please also change the tag to [android] when you [edit] your question to provide the requested details. The [android-studio] tag is for questions concerning the IDE itself.

Comment: Sorry my mistake making the edits now

Answer (score 0):

We're missing a lot of context here that would probably help us help you.

A few things first though:
- The `android:id` property in your XML layout is how you name the View in question.  This is most often how you will reference the View in code.
- The `android:text` property is the user visible text on views like TextView.
- In order for `top_button` to refer to your desired View in your XML layout file, it needs to be bound in code.  There's a couple of normal ways of doing it `findViewById()` and data-binding.

I'm going to assume, for now, that the last step is what you are missing (it seems the most likely culprit at this point)...  Here's a few ways to bind it:

**Method 1: when using an Activity class**

If you're binding `top_button` to your View from an `Activity` class, this should work:

```
private lateinit var top_button // replace View here with your widget's type

fun onCreate(...) {
    super.onCreate(...)
    setContentView(R.layout.<i>your_layout_file_name_here</i>)
    top_button = findViewById(R.id.top_button)
    ...
}
```

**Method 2: when using a Fragment class**

If you're binding `top_button` to your View from a `Fragment` class, it's more like this:

```
private lateinit var top_button: View // replace View here with your widget's type

fun onCreateView(...): View {
    val rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.<i>your_layout_file_name_here</i>)
    top_button = rootView.findViewById(R.id.top_button)
    ...
    return rootView
}
```

**Method 3: when using data-binding**

I prefer this method myself, but you should Google how to setup data-binding in Android as you'll need changes in your build.gradle and all.

- First, change your XML layout to be:

```
<layout>

<!-- your existing layout XML here -->

</layout>
```

Then in your Activity/Fragment, let's say your XML layout file is named `activity_my_cool_screen.xml`, you can do:

```
val binding = ActivityMyCoolScreenBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater())
binding.topButton.setOnClickListener(...)
```

Notice here that the `ActivityMyCoolScreenBinding` class is auto-generated for you.  If it turns red at first, then first verify you've accurately setup data-binding in your project, then if that's good to go, make sure to import the `ActivityMyCoolScreenBinding` class.  If you change your XML layout's filename, then the `ActivityMyCoolScreenBinding` class name will change to match automatically.  But, I'd recommend if you do change the name, that you use Android Studio's refactoring/renaming tools as it'll search your codebase and update it everywhere.  Otherwise, you have to do it by hand (doable, but potentially tedious and error prone).

Good luck!

Comment: What i'm trying to do is have the xml top button code bind to my kotlin code does that help ?

Comment: It does.  I think the methods I listed above will do what you require.